# Make list of variables automatically from other vectors in r

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a matrix of 107 dna sequences (columns) each 10 bases long (rows). I also have a vector of population frequencies called nSamples, and a vector of names for these populations called dnapops. I would like to automatically create a nested list than contains seperately the first 27 sequences as dna1, the next 27 as dna2, the next 17 as dna3.....and so on until all 107 sequences are in their respective population in the list.
This needs to be dynamic as the the number of populations and dna sequences changes from application to application:

$dna1

$dna1$'1'

[1] "g" "t" "g" "a" "t" "t" "c" "c" "g" "g"

$dna1$'2'

[1] "g" "t" "g" "a" "t" "t" "c" "c" "g" "g"

and so on until

$dna1$'27'

[1] "g" "t" "g" "a" "t" "t" "c" "c" "g" "g"

then it goes to dna2 and lists its 27 sequences, then dna3 and lists its 17 sequences.......

```
dna <- matrix(data=sample(c("a","g","c","t"),1070,replace=T),nrow=10,ncol=107)
nSamples <- c(27,27,17,12,1,10,3,1,6,3)
dnapops <- c("dna1","dna2","dna3","dna4","dna5","dna6","dna7","dna8","dna9","dna10")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can replicate the sequence of 'nSamples' with the 'nSamples' and `split` the sequence of columns of 'dna' using that, extract the columns based on the sequence index and `split` by the `col`.

```
lst <- lapply(split(seq_len(ncol(dna)),rep(seq_along(nSamples), nSamples)), 
              function(i) {x1 <- dna[,i, drop=FALSE]
                    split(x1, col(x1)) })
lengths(lst)
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
#27 27 17 12  1 10  3  1  6  3 
lst[[1]][1:5]
#$`1`
#[1] "g" "a" "c" "c" "c" "t" "g" "t" "t" "g"

#$`2`
#[1] "c" "g" "c" "c" "g" "t" "a" "a" "c" "a"

#$`3`
#[1] "a" "c" "c" "a" "a" "c" "a" "c" "c" "a"

#$`4`
#[1] "g" "a" "g" "a" "t" "a" "c" "c" "c" "t"

#$`5`
#[1] "g" "g" "g" "a" "a" "a" "g" "g" "g" "g"
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
dna <- matrix(data=sample(c("a","g","c","t"),1070,replace=T),nrow=10,ncol=107)
```

Comment: That nearly works, except now the dna sequences are merged in each part of the list. How could it be altered so that it was a list of lists of each dna sample? i.e. dna1 had 27 separate dnas, dna2 had 27 separate dnas.... thank you

Comment: The code does not seem to work. The ordering of the bases is not conserved

Comment: @user3651829  I updated the post, please check if this is what you wanted

Comment: @user3651829  Your original matrix `dna` is based on `sample` and you haven't set any seed.  Basically, the output you showed for repeating `"g" "t" "g" "a" "t" "t" "c" "c" "g" "g"` for 27 times is not clear as you have first 27 columns in 'dna' with different values.

Comment: @user3651829  Also, here I am splitting by the sequence of columns i.e. 1st 27 columns in the 'dna' will be the first `list` element (which is again split up to vectors), 2nd 27 columns form the second `list` element and so on.  Otherwise, the repeating sequence is not making sense.